# Using Wordpress on a subfolder with microsoft azure

Tags: iis, virtual-machines, azure, wordpress

I'm implementing a wordpress on Microsoft Azure on a subfolder (something like http://domain.com/blog)

All the servers are on a Windows,

I did a workaround using an external server for the mysql and allocated the php stuff on a subfolder with php.

**The problem** is that this is extremely slow because it has to go from one server to another.

I checked the option of using wordpress with sql server but it doesn't work with the plugins that we use,

And I also tried this solution https://blog.kloud.com.au/2014/11/27/installing-wordpress-in-a-sub-folder-on-azure-websites/ but clear is expensive for a blog.

We can't use subdomains like http://blog.domain.com for a policy issue of the company.

I created a virtualmachine with the bitnami image, and would like if it's possible to use it as a "folder" with some magic trick, or something like cloaking on azure.

Comment: MySQL on another machine shouldn't be particularly slow, unless there's something wrong with your network. MySQL can be installed on Windows no problem at all. I don't really understand the problem you're having, this seems trivial.

Comment: I don't understand the premise... Why don't you just [provision a MySQL server on Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/store-php-create-mysql-database/)? Or are you saying the connection between your Azure webserver and your MySQL is slow? In which case... Did you provision them in the same region?

Comment: it's not windows, it's a microsoft azure server, you can't put mysql without paying extra's and we are already above 10k a month on servers wich is our limit @Tim, the other server is on dreamhost, and the loadtime can be sometimes up to 10 seconds which blocks the access

Comment: @Reaces that mysqlserver cost more than the budget that we have for the blog, it's min 50 dols a month just for the database, the problem is that we are trying to figure out how to put it on the same domain, I checked some documentation and there are workarounds like what I did on the vm, but the php has to be on the subfolder which makes it slow for excel, etc

Comment: So what you're saying is your problem has a solution, you just can't afford it? I'm afraid sometimes that's just the way it is. Not everything can be replaced by cheaper components and keep its performance up.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out if there is another way around without using external parts :), the reason they microsoft charge for the mysql is because it's allocated through a company called cleardb

Comment: @Saikios you don't have to use the clearDB option, you can just create a VM in Azure and install MYSQL.

Comment: @Sam thanks for the tip, will try it out, I'm with the bitnami but it has a few things that make the server go a little bit slower because it's ready for a full wordpress; have you ever try to install wordpress on a subfolder like what I mentioned on azure? (I saw a few cases but most people recommend using subdomains because it breaks down)

Comment: @Saikios I think you are getting hung up on this subfolder thing, I don't think that's your problem. If your DB is in a different data centre to your site that will slow things down. Using a subdomain for your blog is unlikely to slow things down.

Answer (score 1):

Putting MySQL on a server outside your data center is going to introduce significant latency. You need to put your database in the same data center as your app server. The problem here is your budget, which has affected your deployment architecture.

The smallest AWS Linux instance can run a good sized blog, especially if you do caching (eg Nginx page caching). I imagine Azure is similar. Based on the comments below I think you have four solutions:

- Architect this properly - ie get a VM, install everything, and get it
  running
- Pay for a database
- Drop the plugins that don't work
- Set up some kind of a page cache. If you have a predefined system you may not have that option. If you have users logged in a lot it won't help them. If your site is mostly anonymous users then page caching can increase performance as the request doesn't even hit Wordpress, let alone the database. I use page caching in my [Wordpress tutorial](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-pt1-introduction-configuration-downloads/) and it improves performance by a couple of orders of magnitude.

Comment: Hi @tim the technical problem would be how to use vm as a folder domain, if there is any way to do it

Comment: What is an "Azure Server"? Does it have an operating system you can install things on?

Comment: @Tim In his case it does. If for Azure you see something like the above mentioned `I created a virtual machine with the *** image` it is an image offered by a publisher with a machine with pre-configured installation. Otherwise it would be an Azure App/Web Service.

Comment: Ok, then the problem is both financial and that it's been poorly architected. The solution is to do the job properly.

Comment: @Tim thanks a lot for your answer, except for the extra database (budget problem) is what I have  :), A vm running with mysql, I have only the plugins that work, I have a cache activated on wordpress and a plugin; the issue is that I wanted to have everything on the same server and just use a cloaking or something of the kind without affecting the seo